# Why is my launcher not working for this script? ubuntu 20.04

Tags: scripts, launcher

I have a spript "poweriso.sh" that works fine double clicking in the directory.

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.

 export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=.

 ./poweriso

 unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

That is how the file came in the download. I added

```
  #!/bin/bash
```

It did not matter.

I have a .desktop file "poweriso.desktop" that wont launch it.

```
 [Desktop Entry]

 Type=Application

 Terminal=true

 Name=Power ISO

 Icon=/mnt/Linux-stuff/poweriso-x64/iso.png

 Exec=/mnt/Linux-stuff/poweriso-x64/poweriso.sh
```

I think I see a flash of the gui but it does not run.

It does not show in proccesses after trying to run.

.desktop is in ~/.local/share/applications and it shows in launcher menu.

I have been looking at it a long time. Please help.

Comment: Side note: You should [add a shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546) so the system knows what kind of script it is, and how to run it - tl;dr put `#!/usr/bin/env bash` by itself as the first line of your script

Comment: @cocmac That did not help.

Comment: I doubt it will work with relative paths `.` and `./poweriso` - either change those to absolute paths, or it may possibly work as-is if you add a `Path=` specification to your .desktop file to set the working directory

Comment: @steeldriver  I am stuck on stupid. Can you give examples with the information I have given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
./poweriso
```

you indicated in the script to the system means: "find an executable `poweriso` in the current directory (`./`) and run it. When you run the script from a launcher, it is extremely unlikely that the current directory is the one where the script resides.

This for the "why".

Some options:

- In your script, first change to the directory where the executable remains to solve this issue.
- Alternatively, have the `.desktop` launcher change the current directory to that where the executable resides with a `Path=` entry.
- Alternatively, provide the absolute path to the executable `poweriso` in your script, and also indicate that directory in the environmental variables you create so it can find its resources.

By the way, there is no need to `unset` variables in your script. Once the script is finished, also the custom environment set during execution of the script is gone.

Comment: Thank you. cd in script worked without any help. I tried other options yesterday they did not work in this situation. That was so easy, like i said before stuck on stupid.